# GoogleSSO How to detect password change or signed out

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, single-sign-on, google-sso

We are implementing GoogleSSO, in the new API, I am not able to find out how to identify if user is logged out in another tab or if the session is still valid or in these lines. If I want to store the token in cookie for longer duration, how can I keep validating the user ?